How can I set this up for a seamless repeat?
I want to make a seamless pattern swatch of this design and can't figure out how to properly set it up to repeat the colors as shown.


Just the top left 4.. repeat.

Adjust the pattern tile to Brick By Column and change the pattern tile width to allow the proper overlap.

Note the green highlight for the pattern tile.
